# Reading array partially

Tags: php, arrays

I need to read array partially inside a loop, and this is what I'm doing:

```
$list = range(1, 9);
shuffle($list);

print_r($list);

for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "=============== START =============== \n";
        foreach (array_splice($list, $i) as $value) {
            echo $value. "\n";
        }
        echo "=============== END =============== \n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 9
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 5
)
=============== START =============== 
4
6
8
3
7
1
9
2
5
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
=============== END ===============
```

... so it prints the array just once. But I'm expecting the array to print `0-3, 3-6, 6-9` in each iteration.

Expected Output:

```
=============== START =============== 
4
6
8
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
3
7
1
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
9
2
5
=============== END ===============
```

Comment: can you put expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `array_splice($list, $i) as $value`

to: `array_slice($list, $i, 3) as $value`

[array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php): Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

[array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php): Extract a slice of the array

Comment: that outputs from index `0-3` and then `6-9` but not `3-6`

Comment: omit the 'p' from splice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $list = range(1, 9);
    shuffle($list);

    print_r($list);

    $chunks = array_chunk($list,3);

    foreach($chunks as $chunk){
        echo "=============== START =============== \n";

        foreach($chunk as $value){
            echo $value;
        }
        echo  "=============== END =============== \n";
    }



?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is array_chunk an option. Splits the array in chunks of 3, then a foreach loop.

```
$list = range(1, 9);
shuffle($list);
$chunks = array_chunk($list, 3);

foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo "=============== START =============== <br/>\n";
    foreach ($chunk as $value) {
        echo $value . "<br/>\n";

    }
    echo "=============== END ===============<br/> \n";

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$list = range(1, 9);
shuffle($list);

print_r($list);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  $temp = 3 * $i;
  echo "=============== START =============== \n";

   for($k = 0; $k < 3; $k++) {
    $j = $temp + $k;
    echo $list[$j]. "\n";
   }
    echo "=============== END =============== \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your desired output and for achieving this you need to use `array_slice` with the 3rd parameter `length`

```
$list = range(1, 9);
shuffle($list);

echo "<pre>";print_r($list);

for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {

    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
        echo "=============== START =============== \n";
        foreach (array_slice($list, $i,3) as $value) {
            echo $value. "\n";
        }
        echo "=============== END =============== \n";
    }

}

exit;
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 7
)
=============== START =============== 
1
5
8
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
9
2
4
=============== END =============== 
=============== START =============== 
3
6
7
=============== END ===============
```

Comment: how is this different from my answer?

Comment: @lje I was writing when you posted it and my answer is detailed with why i used the 3rd parameter thats it nothing different.